# how to configure view resolver using annotations in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have configured view resolvers in DispatcherServlet xml files. But how to configure view resolver using annotations in spring boot?

Answer (score 4):

From [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html) :

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add
>   additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view
>   controllers etc.) you can add your own @Configuration class of type
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but without @EnableWebMvc. If you wish to
>   provide custom instances of RequestMappingHandlerMapping,
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter or ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver you
>   can declare a WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter instance providing such
>   components.
>
> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your
>   own @Configuration annotated with @EnableWebMvc.

You can do it :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Of course, adapt the prefix and the suffix according to your actual configuration.

---

Edit to handle the redirection to the page when `/` is request :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
     // add a mapping for redirection to index when / requested
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
    }
}
```

Comment: my index.html in in root folder. i want index.html to be opened when i run localhost:8080. how can i do this

Comment: You can add a mapping to do the redirection.I just added this in my answer to illustrate how to do it. But normally you should not need it if index.html is at the root.

Comment: but it shows me this error: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: Indeed it is a fallback. You should edit your question and show the layout of the resource files, it could help to understand :)

Comment: okay, i set prefix to "/WEB-INF/" on above code and mapping for " /index " is       
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String greeting() {
        return "index";
    }
}

Comment: if you use Spring Boot, you should not place the web resources here. Move your `index.html` in `src/main/resources/static` folder of the projet and remove this mapping because it should  not be required and try again.

Comment: ooo thats works fine, is that some default thing spring does? ;)

Comment: Read the **27.1.5 Static Content part**  from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html. You should understand the default properties and behaviors of Spring.